# How to escape single quote ' or double quote " that is located in string using velocity 1.7

Tags: javascript, velocity

I am getting an error of unknown identifier in my js because while its being packed in velocity its being send for example

```
' some'string '
```

as any normal javascript it will end string right after second single quote '

same goes for double quote "

```
"some"string"
```

I tried googling 
Is there any way to skip those quotes that is supported by 1.7 version ( not 2.0 )
Because docs from link https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/velocity/anakia/Escape.html are not very helpful
Thank you

Comment: did you try to escape them with \? eg `'some\"string'` ? or `"some\'string"`? or even the es6 syntax using `

Comment: It should be done within velocity and escaping is not being done with slashes there is special syntax if i can say
But what i managed to find is only for 2.0 like on link here
https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html
I've never done this before, that's the problem